# unable to automatically debug wcf service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I am new to WCF. I have created one sample service to insert the record into the customer table. when running the application i am getting an error -  "Unable to automatically debug 'Home.Service'. The remote procedure could not be debugged. This usually indicates that debugging has not been enabled on the server."

I am using VS 2010.

Can somebody help me pls

The web.config code (as in comment):

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"> 
<!--<assemblies> 
   <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
   <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/> 
   <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
   <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
   </assemblies>-->
</compilation>
```

Comment: With the info and no code details all i can suggest is restart VS and try again and do you have this in your config `<compilation debug="true" />` ?

Comment: I have restarted twice and here is the web.config code - <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
   <!--<assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
</assemblies>-->
</compilation>

Comment: Are you trying to debug from the client side or the service side?

Comment: Hi rune, I am trying to debug from client side.

Comment: @user878488: please **don't post** large code and config snippets in config - no formatting possible and **very hard** to read! Instead: update your original question **by editing it** and provide that new info! Thanks

Comment: Do you use Dubug solution configuration? If so do you deploy a .pdb files on the server?